# cli in golang with Azure AD using MSAL to authenticate user

Tags: go, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I need to create a CLI tool that should list all applications from an Azure AD tenant, applications designated for a specific user.
The user should provide username and password to the cli, no browser interaction is possible. The user has MFA activated and can use the phone to approve MFA. After an access token is obtained the cli will use MS Graph to list the Azure AD applications.
Can someone please suggest a starting point? What auth flow is appropriate? Some examples or documentation is welcome?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the custom commands which custom commands are now generally available. Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/custom-commands).

The Azure Command-Line Interface (CLI) is a cross-platform command-line tool that can be installed locally on Windows computers. You can use the Azure CLI for Windows to connect to Azure and execute administrative commands on Azure resources. The Azure CLI for Windows can also be used from a browser through the Azure Cloud Shell or run from inside a Docker container. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-cli) is the documentation you can follow.

Comment: The tool should be used through ssh, therefore no browser and no windows, just Linux. MFA is activated for the user and they will approve the MFA through their phone (Windows Authenticator).